# A simple reliable P2P communication method suitable for implementing on Embedded Systems

Tags: c, embedded, video-streaming, audio-streaming, p2p

I am trying to implement a method which a client behind a NAT can reach my video/audio encoder device connected to another LAN (behind another NAT), and then my device streams Video and Audio to that client.
Is there anyone who knows how to deal with NAT issue for P2P communication?
I have read and review the UDP hole punching, STUN/TURN/ICE and a few other methods like uPnP protocol and so on. All of them either have uncertainty in transmission or it's different from NAT to NAT or it is complicated to be implemented on my device. 
I am wondering if there is a simpler method to handle this thing?! Since I have to do networking things on my device, unlike PC, it is not very strong and I can't expect a lot of computation. Thus I prefer a simple method.

Thanks~

Answer (score -1):

The 'easiest' way  would be to have 1 device outside both NATs which both devices connect to and acts as a proxy.   From the question you are asking, I think this would be an answer to your problem, AND, that you could probably implement.